# qwt graph plot example

Tags: c++, linux, qt-creator

hello every one i am using qwt and i am new to i want to plot a graph using qwt and qt creator i dont know which librariesoz to include in my qt project to plot a graph i have already installed qwt and also include plugins and library now kindly tell now what i have to do 
with a simple example

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Download the source code of Qwt here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwt/files/qwt-beta/6.0.0-rc5/qwt-6.0.0-rc5.zip/download

Unzip the archive and look inside the "examples" folder.  You could open examples.pro in Qt Creator and compile all the examples or you could open only the example that interest you (ie: examples/curvedemo1/curvedemo1.pro).